# Emulating PHP class magic methods in PHP 4.x

Tags: php, oop

The production server for my current employer is still running PHP 4.x; for some set of reasons, upgrading PHP versions is out of the question.

I'm implementing a web app which heavily relies upon usage of OOP. I've found that I'm able to emulate a good amount of PHP 5 OOP features through little hacks or clever workarounds (generally located in a template base class from which I extend all other classes). Presently, I'm in need of the `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` magic methods for my classes; is there a way to emulate this functionality in PHP 4.x *without* wrapping calls to `serialize()` and `unserialize()` with method calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably accomplish this by renaming and then overriding the built-in `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions using [`rename_function()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) and [`override_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php).  It's definitely a bit of a hack, though.

**Edit:** Oops, I just realized that those are debugger methods, so this probably won't work for you.  [Runkit](http://php.net/runkit) provides the same functionality, but it is an extension which needs to be installed, and I assume you won't be able to do that either if you can't upgrade PHP.

**Edit 2:** In either case, for the sake of clarity and maintainability, I think you're better off just defining your own serialization and deserialization functions wherein you introspect the target object, call special functions if available, and then call `serialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way : those methods, in PHP 5, are invoked by the PHP engine itself.

As you guessed, if you want to change the serialization/deserialization process, you'll have to wrap your calls to `serialize()` and `unserialize()` with some additional code, calling those non-magic-anymore-methods